# Как ускорить вычисление полиноминального хеша

Tags: python, python-3.x, хеширование

Вычисляю полиноминальный хеш на строке s.
Мое решение (метод Горнера):

```
base = int(input())
mod = int(input())
s = input()

first_expr = ord(s[0]) * base + ord(s[1])
for i in range(2, len(s)):
    first_expr = first_expr * base + ord(s[i])

print(first_expr % mod)

# 123    |
# 100003 |=> 6080
# hash   |
```

Как можно ускорить это решение?

Comment: Дайте ссылку на тестирующую систему.

Answer (score 2):

Модуль (`%`) надо вызывать в цикле. У вашего алгоритма сейчас квадратичная сложность. Число цифр `first_expr` растёт пропорционально длине строки. Соответственно замедляются арифметические операции с ним. Это незаметно на коротких строках, но на длинных будет не хорошо.

```
def phash(base, mod, s):
    h = 0
    for c in s:
        h = (h * base + ord(c)) % mod
    return h


base = int(input())
mod = int(input())
s = input()
print(phash(base, mod, s))
```

Comment: понял, спасибо. Ваше решение действительно быстрее, но все равно на некоторых тестах не проходит